# How do I skip an error if the object is not found?

Tags: r

So my line uses dplyr to select certain columns from a data frame to use later on- for example:

```
Test <- dplyr::select(Name, Date, Value, Variable)
```

However, as I am looping this string of code, sometimes for a data frame, Variable cannot be found and thus an error as below is produced and stops the entire code:

```
Error in .f(x[p[i]], ...): object 'Variable' not found
```

How should I go about skipping the rest of the code and moving on to the next iteration when needed?

Thanks

Comment: You could first check if the vars mentioned in your Variables object exist in the data frame by checking to which extent the two names vectors overlap. And then you‘d just select thos vars that exist in both.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `any_of`:

```r
select(head(mtcars), cyl, mpg, any_of("Variable"))
#                   cyl  mpg
# Mazda RX4           6 21.0
# Mazda RX4 Wag       6 21.0
# Datsun 710          4 22.8
# Hornet 4 Drive      6 21.4
# Hornet Sportabout   8 18.7
# Valiant             6 18.1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

vars <- c('a', 'b')

df <- data.frame(a = c(1,2), c = c(3,4))

new_vars <- intersect(vars, names(df))  

test <- df %>%
  select(all_of(new_vars))

test

  a
1 1
2 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The `try()` function allows you to run a line of code that may produce an error, and then carry on even if it returns an error, e.g.

```
{x <- gsfjkhg}; print("cheese")
# Error: object 'gsfjkhg' not found

try({x <- gsfjkhg}); print("cheese")
# Error in try({ : object 'gsfjkhg' not found
# [1] "cheese"
```